# HTTP POST Json format and set Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

```
["client_ID": "0", "username": "asdf@gmail.com", "grant_type": "password", "password": "12345", "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "scope": "adfs.user"]
```

Format convert to this

```
{"client_ID": "2", "username": "asdf@gmail.com", "grant_type": "password", "password": "12345", "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "scope": "adfs.user"}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: let postString: Parameters  = [ "grant_type" : GRANT_TYPE ,"client_ID" : CLIENT_ID ,"client_secret" : CLIENT_SECRET,"username" : emailString, "password" : passwordString,"scope" :  ROLE]

Comment: Sorry we didn't understand the question. What you are actually trying to achieve? Are you trying to convert `Dictionary` into JSON string?

Comment: Alamofire can transform a Swift Dictionary into a JSON Dictionary when sending the data. Did you try anithing? In the ReadMe of the lib, there are sample, explainations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
let params: Parameters = [ "grant_type" : GRANT_TYPE ,"client_ID" : CLIENT_ID ,"client_secret" : CLIENT_SECRET,"username" : emailString, "password" : passwordString,"scope" : ROLE] 
let req = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding:JSONEncoding.default , headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

})
```